# Remove Records with string that = end of another Record's string grouped by another field

Tags: mysql

As clumsy as this may be, I made a Query that steps through and identifies records whose entire name field makes up the end of another name field:

[Finding Contained Records](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/2a5e3e/2)

What I am actually trying to do though is:

1. Find only find those records contained in others that are from the same client, this is as far as I got:

[Trying to group contained records by client field](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/bf016e/6)

2. Delete those records (the ones from each client already contained in another record by that client.

I get I can do this with something like

`Delete from Main where Name='Farm' and Client='Bob'`

But not sure how to turn my select yet into the grouping required.

Comment: What about exact duplicates?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the join condition `T.Name Like Concat('%_', T2.Name)`. That means `T.Name` ends with `T2.Name`, but has at least one more character (`_`) in front of it.

```
Select T.Client,T.Client,T.Name,T2.Name
From Main T
Inner Join Main T2
  On  T2.Client = T.Client
  And T.Name Like Concat('%_', T2.Name)
Where T2.Name != ''
```

Demo: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/bf016e/26

Convert it to a DELETE statement:

```
Delete T2
From Main T
Inner Join Main T2
  On  T2.Client = T.Client
  And T.Name Like Concat('%_', T2.Name)
Where T2.Name != ''
```

Demo: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/9503cd/1

This should also work and might be less cryptic:

```
And T.Name <> T2.Name
And T.Name Like Concat('%', T2.Name)
```

Comment: Had to give you The Answer and a Plus for that thank you. Will make my future string manips much easier :) I did have to change `%_` to `% ` as it take parts of words vs full words out. Otherwise great stuff thank you.