# Removing Records with String Contained in Other Records using 3 tables and Joins

Tags: mysql, join

I previously got a great answer (thank you @Paul Spiegel) on [removing records from a table whose string was contained at the end of another record](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49458112/remove-records-with-string-that-end-of-another-records-string-grouped-by-anot/49459006#49459006). For example,  removing 'Farm' when 'Animal Farm' existed) and grouped by a Client Field.

The problem is, in fact, a little more complex and spans three tables, I'd hoped I could extend the logic easily but it turns out to also be challenging (for me). Instead of one table with `Client` and `Term`, I have three tables:

1. Terms
2. Clients
3. Look-up-Table (LUT) where I store pairs of TermID and ClientID

I have made some progress since initially posting this question so where I stand is I made the `Joins` and resultant `Select` return the fields I want to delete from the Look-up-Table (LUT):

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/479c72/45

The final select being:

`Select Distinct(C.Title),T2.Term From LUT L
Inner Join Terms T
On L.TermID=T.ID 
Inner Join Terms T2
On T.Term Like Concat('% ', T2.Term)
Inner Join Clients C
On C.ID=L.ClientID;`

I am in the process of trying to turn this into a `Delete` with little success.

Comment: Please do not link to external code. The code is the important part here; put it in your question.

Comment: @Nyerguds It isn't external code; it is a `SqlFiddle` with the all the table creates, inserts and joins that do not lend well to the body of the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Append this to your query:

```
Inner Join LUT L2
On  L2.ClientID = L.ClientID
And L2.TermID  = T2.ID
```

That will ensure, that the clients do match and you will get the following result:

```
| ClientID | TermID | ID |          Term | ID |      Term | ID | Title | ClientID | TermID |
|----------|--------|----|---------------|----|-----------|----|-------|----------|--------|
|        1 |      2 |  2 |     Small Dog |  1 |       Dog |  1 |   Bob |        1 |      1 |
|        2 |      5 |  5 | Big Black Dog |  3 | Black Dog |  2 | Alice |        2 |      3 |
```

To delete the corresponding rows from the `LUT` table, replace `Select *` with `Delete L2`.

But deleting the terms is more tricky. Since it's a many-to-many relation, the term may belong to multiple clients. So you can't just delete them. You will need to cleanup up the table in a second statement. That can be done with the following statement:

```
Delete T
From Terms T
Left Join LUT L
On L.TermID = T.ID
Where L.TermID Is Null
```

Demo: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/b17659/1

Note that in this case the term `Medium Dog` will also be deleted, since it doesn't belong to any client.

Comment: I am actually trying to delete from the LUT which is dynamically created each day. I got to here `http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/37b3c8/3` which selects the right IDs from LUT to remove but cannot yet turn it into delete

Comment: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/c09b4a/2 I changed the Select to ut the LUT first so I could change to a Delete but as you can see I get the error `You can't specify target table 'L' for update in FROM clause`

Comment: @user3649739 It's a different question.. But: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/a3edeb/1 - You need to wrap the subquery to avoid the error. Or you can rewrite it to a pure JOIN query.

Comment: I marked your answer as correct as all I needed to do was change `Delete T` to `Delete L` as you see here: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/a0fe4f/4, thank you